Many-Worlds Interpretation Question
I had a quick question, in Dr. Sean Carrol's Royal Institute talk, he shows some Uranium in a cloud chamber. Direct link is below. (This example and the Veritasiums walking droplets are my current absolute favorite quantum examples.)
My question is, for the emitted radioactive observable waves, each spins up a different many-world, right?
https://youtu.be/5hVmeOCJjOU?si=nlzG78WeF-zCUyMU&start=834

+1 for the link. Here is another Veritasium/Carrol video that explains the sam thing more simply. Perhaps it will help. Or perhaps you have already seen it. Parallel Worlds Probably Exist. Here’s Why

MWI is simply based on a misunderstanding of quantum mechanics. In the standard theory the wave function is a description of the average behavior of an unmeasured quantum mechanical ensemble, i.e. it assumes that we can make an infinite number of copies of the same experiment. Everett, the guy who invented MWI didn't understand this and interpreted the wave function as an actual physical description of an individual quantum system. This counting mistake literally multiplies the physical world by infinity. So, no, nothing "spins up a different world". MWI is a trivial counting error.

@FlatterMann the wave function is a description of the average behavior Do you mean the distribution of the behavior of an ensemble?

@FlatterMann "In the standard theory the wave function is a description of the average behavior of an unmeasured quantum mechanical ensemble" -> This is already an interpretation of the mathematics of quantum mechanics. You can't judge an interpretation through the prism of another one. Your argument is biased by your own interpretation of QM.

@MariusLadegårdMeyer Yes. It's the behavior of the unmeasured ensemble, to be precise. As soon as we do measurements, we have to either include some form of density matrix approach or the Born rule. Probabilities are averages in the sense of the law of large numbers. I am using this in a somewhat naive sense here, since the different levels of physical divergences in quantum field theory make this a non-trivial topic.

@JeanbaptisteRoux The Born rule makes it absolutely clear that we are talking about an ensemble. It reduces the quantum mechanical ensemble to a statistical ensemble. Linearity and unitarity of the theory are trivial consequences of an ensemble assumption. They don't just fall out of the sky. They follow directly from the fact that we can derive quantum mechanics rationally from Kolmogorov's axioms. If you take that away then quantum mechanics does, of course, have to look like magic from the gods, but if you start with Kolmogorov QM becomes a trivial geometric partition of unity.

@FlatterMann If you say so, it must be true! More seriously, I've never said that anything has fallen out of the sky, or that QM looks like magic from the gods. I was pointing out that your view of quantum mechanics is just an interpretation of mathematics (which is agnostic of physics.), and you dove deep into it. But I'm not surprised because if I'm not mistaken, you are an experimentalist. We have different points of view about QM: You took the risky way of overinterpreting mathematics, while I chose not to trust my brain and "shut up and calculate".

@JeanbaptisteRoux I don't say so. Nature does. You can verify for yourself that individual quantum events are statistically independent. It starts with you grabbing a single quantum detector like a photomultiplier tube or a Geiger-Mueller counter and then you take a time series. You will soon notice that you can't find a formula that can predict the next quantum based on the previous n quanta. That is what Kolmogorov's axioms are expressing: independent sample sets. At most you can ask yourself how nature manages to produce this independence. That turns out comes from relativity.

@FlatterMann Comments are not for extended discussions so this will be my last message. "Nature" or "Reality" or whatever, are words we put on phenomena we experience. This means we are always doomed to see those things through the prism of our mortal, biased, minds. For each mathematical model, there are several interpretations. You have yours, I chose not to have any. Interpretations are unfalsifiable unless there is either a better theory or if they add assumptions to the initial one. MWI seems until now unfalsifiable, and so seems yours.

@JeanbaptisteRoux Let me repeat this: statistical independence of quanta is not an interpretation. It's an experimental result that anybody can verify at home with very little effort.

In the MWI different versions of a system can interfere with one another and when interference effects are strong it doesn't make much sense to say they're in different universes because they affect one another strongly.
A radioactive atom in a cloud chamber and the radiation it emits are described by a state that evolves continuously over time and interacts continuously with its environment.
This interaction produces records in the environment and this suppresses interference between different versions of the record: this is called decoherence. In particular, instances that are far apart have a lower probability of interfering than instances that are closer:
https://arxiv.org/abs/1111.2187
You can pick some level of interference and then say any versions of the system that interfere less than that level are separate universes. The universes are emergent and so there isn't such a thing as exactly when a new universe emerges:
https://arxiv.org/abs/1111.2189
In addition, the spread of information happens locally so an event in one place won't result in different versions of other systems elsewhere until later:
https://arxiv.org/abs/2008.02328
You should think of the creation of new universes as being a bit like a river splitting into two rivers. When you regard the rivers as split is a pragmatic issue rather than being built into the laws of hydrodynamics. Also, there will be places near the split where it doesn't make much sense to say whether a given volume of water is in this or that river. Likewise, universes are an approximation and so there isn't really a hard and fast rule for how many universes there are or when a new universe is created. It doesn't make sense to say that the creation of new universes is literally continuous because of interference effects being stronger at small scales of space and time but it also doesn't make sense in practice to say that if you see two cloud chamber bubbles one metre apart they're in the same universe.

Thank you so much, I need to read these papers and digest everything here. I SO appreciate this! Hope your day goes great.

I've been contemplating your response and appreciate your river analogy. May I ask, if it makes sense, to imagine observation as amounts of environmental decoherence, perhaps visualized as where this video starts, a river that over time flows in different paths but never looses energy? https://youtu.be/NYA6GF1uAa8?si=uQ9uJuFMFDQHS3yX&t=179

An observation is just an interaction that produces records so an observation produces decoherence as described above. The river analogy is just about something that splits in a slightly messy but still recognisable way on a large enough scale. You shouldn't take it more seriously than that.
